# label and Onehottencodeing in python using sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, sklearn-pandas

I have created array from a dataframe :

```
X = data.loc[:, ['a','b', 'c' , 'd', 'e' , 'f']].values
```

Now, I would like to LableEnocde and OneHotEncode 'b', 'd', 'e' column which are type of object or string

how can I Labelcode and Onehotencode multiple columns here?

**Note**: This is not dataframe and `pd.get_dummies()` is hanging the system

Comment: You can use LabelEncoder from sklearn

Comment: Yes, but it is working for one coloumn at a time ; I would like to lable encode all the three colum in one go

Comment: Why don't you loop though three columns and encode seperatly.?